# Application vs Container authentication in EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-2.x

I am fresher to EJB, working on a maintenance application that is using EJB2.0. I am just going through the application code and trying to understand it. It has got ejb-jar.xml with some session beans as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 
2.0//EN' 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd'>
<ejb-jar>
<enterprise-beans>
  <session>
     <ejb-name>StatelessBean</ejb-name>
     <home>com.example.interfaces.StatelessBeanHome</home>
     <remote>com.example.interfaces.StatelessBean</remote>
     <local-home>com.example.interfaces.StatelessBeanLocalHome</local-home>
     <local>com.example.interfaces.StatelessBeanLocal</local>
     <ejb-class>com.example.interfaces.StatelessBeanSession</ejb-class>
     <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
     <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

     <security-identity> 
        <use-caller-identity>
     </security-identity>

     <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>eis/SAPFactory</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
        <re-sharing-scope>Shareable</re-sharing-scope>
     </resource-ref>

  </session>
</enterprise-beans> 
</ejb-jar>
```

I see that the resource authentication can be either **Application** or **Container** based, in the above snippet it is **Application**, in some other applications I have seen it being mentioned as **Container**, what exactly is the difference between them? When to use over other. Also, the transaction type is also specified as **Container**, please throw some light on this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<res-auth>Application</res-auth>` means that the application will perform login to the resource. For example, for JDBC, that means the application will use `getConnection(user, password)`.  `<res-auth>Container</res-auth>` allows the login credentials to be supplied by the application server, typically through configuration provided by the server administrator.  Container-managed authentication is generally preferred to avoid hard-coding user/password information in the application or needing to invent a secondary mechanism for providing configuration to the application.

`<transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>` for an EJB means that by default the EJB container will implicitly begin transactions when an EJB method is called and commit/rollback (depending on exceptions thrown) when the EJB method ends.  Additionally, per-method transaction attributes can be used to modify the behavior of the container-managed transaction (suspend/reject existing transactions when a method is called, and choose not to start a global transaction at all).  `<transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>` means that the EJB must begin/commit/rollback itself using `UserTransaction`.

Comment: For Container authentication, can't we provide harcoded user name and password like getConnection(user,password)?

Comment: You could, but avoiding that is the whole point of container-managed authentication.